# align div whith background image

Tags: css, background, alignment

I just want align the `background` with my div where I have the text.

I have this code: (Please, resize the window for see the effect)
http://jsfiddle.net/BcqLK/

```
.texto1Home{ 
  width: 48.1%;
  color: #58585A;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px red;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 13.75%;
  left: 25.75%
}
```

And I want this result: (is an image)
http://jsfiddle.net/qYVL4/

Comment: In normal cases it is the divs which need to be positioned according to the image and not image according to the divs

Comment: is what I'm trying to do, what would you suggest? thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

[EDIT] http://jsfiddle.net/BcqLK/6/

Basically you annotate the container with:

```
position:relative
```

After that position the rest of the content with an absolute positioning inside the container. Also I didn't use % but pixels for the positioning. Also it is important to set static image size, otherwise you should really use % or something like that for the alignment.

Regards

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but I really need something like this, http://jsfiddle.net/qYVL4/ try to resize the window :)